# System.IO.IOException: 'El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Tengo problemas para copiar una imagen que tengo en una carpeta hacia otra.
Cuando escojo la imagen del `openFileDialog1` y quiero copiarla a otra dirección me sale la excepción:

> System.IO.IOException: 'El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo
>   'E:\Raul Humberto Juliao Colina\Pictures\50
>   años\812c0a8c-7b25-412c-abcd-3c2d2cad7ebb.jpg' porque está siendo
>   utilizado en otro proceso.'

Esta es la sección de código que hace eso.

```
            this.openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"E:\Raul Humberto Juliao Colina\Pictures";
            this.openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            this.openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Images Files";
            this.openFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF,*.PNG,*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF";
            this.openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            String folder = "E:\\Images";
            String destFile;
            foreach(String img in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder) == true)
                {

                    destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, img);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(img, destFile, true);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el `OpenFileDialog` esta bloqueando el acceso a los archivos que se seleccionan. Por eso, si declaras el `OpenFileDialog` dentro de un bloque `using`, se libera la selección para continuar trabajando con la lista:

```
string[] fileNames;

using(openFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new openFileDialog())
{
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"E:\Raul Humberto Juliao Colina\Pictures";
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Images Files";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF,*.PNG,*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF";
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

    if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileNames = openFileDialog1.FileNames
    }
}

string folder = "E:\\Images";
if (Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    //aqui informas que la carpeta no existe o la creas
}

foreach(string img in fileNames)
{
    string destFile = Path.Combine(folder, img);
    File.Copy(img, destFile, true);
}
```

Comment: Sigue saliendo la misma excepción.